# chr() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python

i was following a tutorial for an brainfuck interpreter, but i encontered a problem: every time i use the "," in the interpreter it gives that error:

```
print(chr(int(stack[stack_pointer]),end=""))
TypeError: chr() takes no keyword arguments
```

the problematic code is:

```
user_input = []
elif code[x] == ",":
        if user_input == []:
            user_input = list(input() + "\n")
        stack[stack_pointer] = ord(user_input.pop(0))
```

Comment: Your parenthesis are messed up

Comment: Yes, you are passing the `end` parameter to `chr`. The error tells you the problem.

Comment: Your "problematic code" snippet doesn't even contain a call to `chr`.

Comment: i fixed the parenthesis and now it works, so 0x5453 the problem wasnt in the  "problematic code"

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the parenthesis and now it works, so 0x5453 the problem wasnt in the "problematic code"

Comment: You've already submitted this as a comment. And then copied it as an answer. At least cut the irrelevant parts out.